# Probability that in a row of 12 with random seating, two specific individuals are exactly two seats apart

Tags: probability, combinatorics

Persons A and B, along with 10 others, are randomly seated in a row of 12 chairs. I want to find the probability that they are separated by exactly two seats.

I know there are $12!$ possible seating arrangements. I sketched a diagram and found $17$ possible ways for two specific people to be seated two chairs apart. Since A and B can swap positions, this number would be multiplied by 2 to get 34 ideal scenarios.

Since the other ten people's seats are irrelevant, there are $10!$ ways for them to be seated for each scenario in which A and B are two seats apart.

So by this thinking, there are $34*10!$ arrangements in which A and B are exactly two seats apart. Hence the probability would be $\frac{34*10!}{12!}$, or about 25%.

This seems far too large, though, so I am concerned that I have an error in my thought process somewhere.

Comment: $17$?  If we suppose that $A$ is seated nearer the front, then $A$ can be seated in seats $1$ through $9$, no?  That would make $9$ possibilities.  Same if $B$ is seated earlier...making for a total of $18$.  Or am I misunderstanding?

Comment: You are correct, I mistakenly double-counted many of the seating arrangements.

Comment: Otherwise your approach is fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Say $A$ sits before $B$ in the row. Then $A$ can sit on seat no. $1$ through $9$, and $B$ sits on the third seat to the right of $A$. So there are $9$ ways to seat $A$ and $B$ in this manner. The remaining $10$ people permute across the rest of the seats in $10!$ ways. Note that we only considered $A$ to the left of $B$; $B$ might as well sit to the left of $A$. So we need to multiply by $2!$. The total ways to seat them are $10!\times9\times2!$ and the required probability is $\frac{10!\times9\times2!}{12!}=3/22$.

Answer (score 1):

There are $C(12,2)= 12(11)/2 = 66$ possible pairs of seats for A and B and these are equally likely to occur. Of those, the pairs with a distance of 3 are of the form $(j, j+3)$ for $j = 1,2, ...9$.

So the desired probability is $9/66 = 3/22$. (i.e. by symmetry, you can ignore the other $10$ people and the ordering of A and B as long as you are consistent about it).